# how does sql developer determine the version of oracle client

Tags: oracleclient

I am aware that sql developer itself does not need oracle client to work.
But when I issued this statement to see which version of oracle client is currently in use:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  s.client_version FROM   v$session_connect_info s
WHERE  s.sid = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SID');
```

I got this response:

```
>>Query Run In:Query Result
CLIENT_VERSION                         
----------------------------------------
11.2.0.3.0
```

I am surprised because there is no oracle client 11.2.0.3.0 declared in my path environment: (oracle client 12.2 and oracle 12.1 yes, but no 11.2 )

```
C:\Windows\system32>path
PATH=D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\;D:\app\client\flk\product\12.2\bin;D:\app\client\flk\product\12.1.0\client_1;D:\app\client\flk\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;D:\ora12\product\12.1.0\ODT;D:\ora12\product\12.1.0\ODT\bin;D:\ora12\ODT\product\12.1.0\client_1;D:\ora12\ODT\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;D:\ora12\product\12.1.0\client\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;D:\;D:\Bins32;D:\Bins64;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\flk\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\flk\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\flk\.dotnet\tools;d:\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

nor was it recorded in the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE (no oracle entry)

So where does it get the 11.2.0.3.0 from? Where else should I look? and is it actually the version to be used in my workstation?

Comment: If it doesn't need oracle client to work, then it probably bundles/emulates one?